# Using SharedPreferences for ColorPicker Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, color-picker

In my app I've `ColorPicker` that is `AmbilWarna color picker`. When I select the desired color from `ColorPicker`, it works like charm. But when I close and restart the Activity, the color changes to default. Hence I'm trying to use `SharedPreferences` to make it work, I've tried `SharedPreferences` in EVERY way to make this succeed but it's not working! Trying to solve this problem from weeks, but no solution! Any help would be gladly appreciated! Here's my code:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.preferences);
    }

    public void colorpicker() {
        AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this, 0xff0000ff,
                new OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
                        MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.activity_main)
                                .setBackgroundColor(color);
                    }

                });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you try to use `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: I tried to save data with SharedPreferences in public void onOk, and retrieve the infrormation from onCreate, my previous tries are not going to work at all, I've realized that...

Comment: I don't see any shared preferences code. Please can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPrefrence colors;
    Editor editor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.preferences);
        colors=getSharedPrefrences("MyColor",1);

        int colorcode=shared.getInt("color", 0);
        if(colorcode!=0)
        {

           MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.activity_main)
                            .setBackgroundColor(colorcode);
        }
   }

   public void colorpicker() {
    AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this, 0xff0000ff,
            new OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
                    MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.activity_main)
                            .setBackgroundColor(color);
                   edit=colors.edit();
                   edit.putInt("color",color);
                   edit.commit();
                }

            });
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know how should I thank you!!!!!!!!! I was not even able to sleep at night because of this problem!!! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: no needs of thanks bro  you can contact me  if you face any issue in android

Comment: deepanshu77777@gmail.com

Comment: @DeepanshuGandhi I am trying the same to save with `SharedPrefences` but here are some declared types which for me are unknowns.
`colors=getSharedPrefrences("MyColor",1);

        int colorcode=shared.getInt("color", 0);`